# Get count of combinations of rows having different values in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want get count of combinations of rows having different values in different columns.

Sample Data as below:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| GUID | Column1 | Column2 |
+------+---------+---------+
| XXX  | A       | aaa     |
| XXX  | B       | bbb     |
| YYY  | C       | ccc     |
| YYY  | D       | ddd     |
| XXX  | A       | aaa     |
| XXX  | B       | bbb     |
+------+---------+---------+
```

I am expecting following result. So XXX should be 2 as we are having 2 records in which Column1=A, Column2=aaa and Column1=B, Column2=bbb (Combination of two different columns values)

XXX 2

YYY 1

Comment: Requirements are not clear: there is no row with `Column1=aaa`

Comment: I updated text.  Column1=A, Column2=aaa and Column1=B, Column2=bbb

Comment: What if there is a `XXX|C|ccc`? What's the expected result?

Comment: XXX/C/ccc will be never happened.  There will be only two records for XXX having different value of Column1 and Column2

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `GUID` and `Column2`, then take the max of `count(*)` to get the number of  combinations:

```
declare @tmp table ([GUID] varchar(3), Column1 varchar(1), Column2 varchar(3))
insert into @tmp values ('XXX','A','aaa'),('XXX','B','bbb'),('YYY','C','ccc'),
                        ('YYY','D','ddd'),('XXX','A','aaa'),('XXX','B','bbb')

select T.[GUID], max(T.cnt) as count_combinations 
from (
    select [GUID], Column2, count(*) as cnt 
    from @tmp
    group by [GUID], Column2
) T
group by T.[GUID]
```

Results:

[image]